# Error when utilizing Gibbon gem via delayed_job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Without delayed_job, this code works fine; if I include delayed_job, I get an error of `uninitialized constant EmailNewsletter::Gibbon` with every attempt the worker makes.

Rails 3.0.7, [Gibbon](https://github.com/amro/gibbon) 0.1.5 (a gem for working with MailChimp), delayed_job 2.1.4.

**Controller**

```
def subscribe
  email = params[:email]
  EmailNewsletter.subscribe(email)
  render(:update) do |page|
    page << "...view update code..."
  end
end
```

**lib/email_newsletter.rb**

```
module EmailNewsletter
  def self.subscribe(email)
    g = Gibbon::API.new('api_key_here', :id => 'list_id_here')
    g.listSubscribe(:email_address => email)
  end
end
```

With the above code, if I post an email address to /subscribe, everything works fine. I want to incorporate delayed_job so that my app doesn't feel slow if MailChimp takes a beat too long to respond.

**Controller**

```
def subscribe
  email = params[:email]
  EmailNewsletter.delay.subscribe(email)
  render(:update) do |page|
    page << "...view update code..."
  end
end
```

It looks like the job goes into the delayed_job table just fine. The `handler` data is:

```
--- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMethod 
object: !ruby/module EmailNewsletter
method_name: :subscribe
args: 
- email@example.com
```

A second later the worker picks it up and runs, and I get an error: `uninitialized constant EmailNewsletter::Gibbon`.

`application.rb` includes `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)`.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

For clarification, the line that the error is being thrown on is

`g = Gibbon::API.new('api_key_here', :id => 'list_id_here')`

I have also tried

`g = ::Gibbon::API.new('api_key_here', :id => 'list_id_here')`

Comment: Did you restart your DJ process?

Answer (score 2):

it just can't find the Gibbon libs

```
require 'gibbon' #in the module to help it find it
```

-7 months later, but hey

Or better yet, there is no Gibbon::API class, Gibbon itself is the class, not a module.

```
api = Gibbon.new("abc123-us2")
```

Comment: In which module did you put it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include delayed_job gem in your gemfile. Can you try that once.

```
 gem 'delayed_job'
```